# Discrepancy between GTiff and MEM drivers

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff

I was expecting that both the drivers would behave the same way, except that 'MEM' will not create the file.

However, in this test 'MEM' pass, but 'GTiff' does not.
Can someone explain why?

```python
class TestMEMVsGTiff(unittest.TestCase):

    @staticmethod
    def check(driver_type):

        temp_tif = tempfile.mktemp(suffix='.tif')
        data = np.array([[[4, 7, 7, 7, 2, 7.],
                         [4, 7, 7, 7, 2, 7.],
                         [4, 7, 7, 7, 2, 7.],
                         [4, 7, 7, 2, 2, 7.],
                         [4, 7, 7, 2, 2, 7.],
                         [4, 7, 7, 10, 2, 7.]],
                        [[2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.],
                         [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.],
                         [0, 1., 0, 0, 0, 1.],
                         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
                         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.],
                         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.]]], dtype=np.float32)
        src_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName(driver_type).Create(temp_tif, 6, 6, 2,
                                                    gdalconst.GDT_Float32)

        src_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(data[0, :, :])
        src_ds.GetRasterBand(1).SetNoDataValue(2)
        src_ds.GetRasterBand(2).WriteArray(data[1, :, :])
        # src_ds.GetRasterBand(2).SetNoDataValue()
        src_ds.SetGeoTransform([10, 1, 0, 10, 0, -1])
        src_ds.FlushCache()

        dst_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('MEM').Create('', 3, 3, 2,
                                                    gdalconst.GDT_Float32)
        dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).SetNoDataValue(3)
        dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).Fill(3)
        dst_ds.SetGeoTransform([10, 2, 0, 10, 0, -2])

        gdal.ReprojectImage(src_ds, dst_ds, '', '', gdal.GRA_Average)
        got_data = dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
        expected_data = np.array([[5.5, 7, 7],
                                  [5.5, 7, 7],
                                  [5.5, 8, 7]])
        np.testing.assert_array_equal(got_data, expected_data)
        band2 = dst_ds.GetRasterBand(2).ReadAsArray()
        np.testing.assert_array_equal(band2, np.array([[1., 0., 0.5],
                                                       [0.25, 0., 0.75],
                                                       [0., 0., 0.]]))

    def test_mem(self):
        self.check('MEM')

    def test_gtiff(self):
        self.check('GTiff')
```

Comment: Here you create the MEM dst_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('MEM') but where do you define the GTiff output?

Comment: For both `driver_type` tests, the `dst_ds` is created by 'MEM' driver.

Comment: Note that the `band1` test passes, the band2 test fails for 'GTiff' driver. This is the band1 test: `np.testing.assert_array_equal(got_data, expected_data)`. It works for both drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem with the `GTiff` driver.

The problem is that I was not assigning a `noDataValue` to `band2`.

There is a difference between the `GTiff` and the `MEM` drivers.

When left unassigned, in the `Gtiff` driver assigns a `nodatavalue` for `band2` to be equal to `band1` noDataValue. However, the `MEM` driver does not.

This inconsistency should be fixed.

The following unitest will pass:

```
class TestMEMVsGTiff(unittest.TestCase):

@staticmethod
def check(driver_type):

    temp_tif = tempfile.mktemp(suffix='.tif')

    data = np.array([[[4, 7, 7, 7, 2, 7.],
                     [4, 7, 7, 7, 2, 7.],
                     [4, 7, 7, 7, 2, 7.],
                     [4, 7, 7, 2, 2, 7.],
                     [4, 7, 7, 2, 2, 7.],
                     [4, 7, 7, 10, 2, 7.]],
                    [[2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.],
                     [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.],
                     [0, 1., 0, 0, 0, 1.],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.]]], dtype=np.float32)
    src_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName(driver_type).Create(temp_tif, 6, 6, 2,
                                                gdalconst.GDT_Float32)

    src_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(data[0, :, :])
    src_ds.GetRasterBand(1).SetNoDataValue(2)
    src_ds.GetRasterBand(2).WriteArray(data[1, :, :])
    src_ds.GetRasterBand(2).SetNoDataValue(3)
    src_ds.SetGeoTransform([10, 1, 0, 10, 0, -1])
    src_ds.FlushCache()

    print src_ds.ReadAsArray()
    print src_ds.GetRasterBand(2).GetNoDataValue()

    dst_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('MEM').Create('', 3, 3, 2,
                                                gdalconst.GDT_Float32)
    dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).SetNoDataValue(3)
    dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).Fill(3)
    dst_ds.SetGeoTransform([10, 2, 0, 10, 0, -2])

    gdal.ReprojectImage(src_ds, dst_ds, '', '', gdal.GRA_Average)
    band1 = dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
    np.testing.assert_array_equal(band1, np.array([[5.5, 7, 7],
                                                   [5.5, 7, 7],
                                                   [5.5, 8, 7]]))
    band2 = dst_ds.GetRasterBand(2).ReadAsArray()
    print band2
    np.testing.assert_array_equal(band2, np.array([[1., 0., 0.5],
                                                   [0.25, 0., 0.75],
                                                   [0., 0., 0.]]))


def test_mem(self):
    self.check('MEM')

def test_gtiff(self):
    self.check('GTiff')
```

Comment: The nodata handling is documented in http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html: `GDAL stores band nodata value in the non standard TIFFTAG_GDAL_NODATA ASCII tag (code 42113) for files created with the default profile GDALGeoTIFF. Note that all bands must use the same nodata value. When BASELINE or GeoTIFF profile are used, the nodata value is stored into a PAM .aux.xml file.` You can add your comments (and patch) to this ticket https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/2083.